# C++11 usage of delete specifier vs private functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I am in the process of boning up on my C++ (as in, attempting to get into more modern-style coding) and am looking at the delete specifier. It is my understanding that it is used to make sure that certain functionality cannot be defined or called. If I understand it correctly, this is primarily within the domain of assignment and copy. I am not quite sure what the difference is between using the delete specifier and just making those functions private.

For instance, what is the difference between:

```
 class Foo {
 private:
      Foo& operator(const Foo&);
      Foo(const Foo&);     
 };
```

And

```
 class Bar {
 public:
      Bar& operator(const Bar&) = delete;
      Bar(const Bar&) = delete;
 };
```

In other words: what does using the delete specifier gain? Is it just to make things look nicer?

Comment: [This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) might help explain how the delete function specifier works, if you haven't already read it.

Comment: delete takes action at compile time and is specific.  If a friend accidentally used the private copy constructor, the error would only be apparent at link time and the error message might not be so informative.

Answer (score 4):

One obvious difference is that if you make the function private, then it is still accessible from within the class and any friends.

An explicitly deleted function is not usable anywhere, so you know simply from that one line that it's never used, without having to inspect the implementation.

You can make the function both private and deleted: then its participation in overload resolution is more consistent.

Comment: I agree with the first two statements, but I would declare deleted functions public. To quote from Scott Meyers 'Effective Modern C++':
`When client code tries to use a member function, C++ checks accessibility before deleted status. When client code tries to use a deleted private function, some compilers complain only about the function being private, even though the function’s accessibility doesn’t really affect whether it can be used.`

Comment: Thanks @maddin45; I knew I'd learn something!  P.S. could you take off the code markup from your comment?  It makes it hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, I was too late. You can only edit comments for a short while. :(

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: uses of a deleted function make the program ill-formed and you are notified at compile-time, uses of a function that is not defined end in an odd error that comes out of the linker.

---

As an example, there is a relevant part of the standard that states:

> A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly, other than to declare it, is ill-formed.

Therefore, the following [compiles just fine](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gFKFVReAz9XpObQ5):

```
struct S {
    void f();
};

template<typename T, void (T::*M)() = &T::f>
void g() {}

int main() {
    g<S>();
}
```

While [the code below does not](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2PoYPf4fI7720Pac):

```
struct S {
    void f() = delete;
};

template<typename T, void (T::*M)() = &T::f>
void g() {}

int main() {
    g<S>();
}
```

That's because in the second case the code is ill-formed and you have a compile-time error in any case, no matter if you are going to use or not `M`. In the second case, you get an error out of the linker only if you try to use it:

```
template<typename T, void (T::*M)() = &T::f>
void g() {
    T t;
    (t.*M)();
}
```

---

Of course, compile-time errors are much better to prevent issues. The example uses public functions, but making them private doesn't prevent from using them within the class in similar ways. That's just a toy example to show a possible difference.

Answer (score 1):

**It's simpler.**

This way, your intent is clearly stated and your compiler can outright say "calling this function is prohibited".

Otherwise you're relying on:

- access control (for attempted calls from outside of the class), or
- the linker giving you an "undefined reference" near the end of your build process. That's kind of okay for small programs where you can quickly find out what's going on, but for deep class hierarchies where some many-times-over encapsulated object cannot be copied but has not been `delete`d, good luck debugging that.